# Can we use Identity server 4 and Access token valid tor in sample API project?

Tags: identityserver4

1. I was using identity server 4 separate project and Web API separate
   project.
2. Configure identity server into the start up of web API project. This
   flow currently i am using.
3. But my doubt is Can i use identity server 4 and identity server
   access token validation process in sample web API project.

Identity server Startup:

```
services.AddMvc();
            services.AddIdentityServer().AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(AuthConfiguration.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(AuthConfiguration.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(AuthConfiguration.GetClients()).AddProfileService<ProfileService>().AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Web API Client startup :

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
               .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
               {
                   options.Authority =ConfigHelper.AppSettings["Auth:ServerURL"];
                   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                   options.ApiName =  ConfigHelper.AppSettings["Auth:APIName"];
               });
```

Comment: do still need help ?

Comment: yes I need Help